# how this example in computer architecture is possible for main memory?

Tags: memory, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I read my notes as follows:

[image: This Example]

My challenge is how it's possible that we have (2^14)-1 words? how it was calculated?

We have 2^16 addressable unit divide by 2^1 (1 byte or 8 bit) makes 2^15 not 2^14. where is my mistake?

Comment: A `word` is defined a 32bit unit, 2^16 8bit units (bytes) can give you 2^14 32bit units (words)

Comment: very niec. @tinazmu please post it as an answer I get it

Comment: 2^1 bytes is 2 bytes.  Maybe you meant 2^0 bytes = 1 byte?  If you only have 1 byte, it requires 0 address bits to select one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addressable units are bytes. With 16 bit addressing, that's 2^16 of them. 32 bit words are 4 bytes, so 2^16 / 4 (or 2^2) = 2^14.

That's assuming the addressing of words must be word-aligned. If words can be byte aligned, words can overlap, with one word starting at each byte (except the top or memory). That's not the normal case though.

Comment: Even in systems that support unaligned word loads/stores, you wouldn't say memory **capacity** is 2^16 - 3 words.  Usually when you're talking about multiple words, they're not overlapping each other, e.g. an array of 10 words, even if the start position is unaligned.  If you did want to talk about the number of possible addresses from which you could do an unaligned word load, you'd need to be explicit about that, not using words like "size" or "capacity".